# Error while doing HTTP Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, typhoeus

I am using Typhoeus gem to execute HTTP requests in my rails Application. The request is as follows.

```
 data = {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
 header =  { "Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept"=>"application/json"}
 request = Typhoeus::Request.post("www.example.com",:body=> data.to_json,:headers => header)
```

here while executing this the auth_token has been converted to auth%5Ftoken=abcd. Actually my API expecting the parameter auth_token. Because of this API is not allowing to access it. It's throwing unauthorized error. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think your code has a typo '"www.example.com":body=> data.to_json' should be "www.example.com",:body=> data.to_json. Otherwise it looks fine to me {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}.to_json will def create "{\"auth_token\":\"abcd\",\"employee\":{\"method\":\"add_employee\"}}" and not auth%5Ftoken=abcd. There must be something else broken. Try running it in a console or create a test.

Comment: @StanWiechers   that comma is typing mistake. i tried. it's encoding while doing request. it converts auth_token to auth%5Ftoken=abcd

Comment: See my answer using RestClient to illustrate the correct sending of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected that issue with to_query. Actually to_query is parsing the actual data to the API

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using RestClient that shows a correct submission of the data, I expect Typhoeus not to be different:

```
 data = {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
 header =  { "Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept"=>"application/json"}
 RestClient.post("www.example.com", data.to_json, header){ |response, request, result| 
       puts "PAYLOAD:"+request.args[:payload]
 }
```

Here is the payload, as expected:

```
 PAYLOAD: "{\"auth_token\":\"abcd\",\"employee\":{\"method\":\"add_employee\"}}"
```

Using Typhoeus:

```
 data = {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
 header =  { "Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept"=>"application/json"}
 request = Typhoeus::Request.post("www.example.com",:body=> data.to_json,:headers => header)
 request.request.original_options[:body]
```

As expected, this is the payload of the request. So your code is good!

```
 "{\"auth_token\":\"abcd\",\"employee\":{\"method\":\"add_employee\"}}"
```

Comment: i should use Typhoeus gem

Comment: Updated the answer. This shows that the correct data is send, a json string.

Comment: no yaar. while hitting the API its doing encode. i.e., _ to %5F

Comment: Well the API/Backend is a different element, but the sending of the request is certainly correct.

Comment: why is this downvoted? I am trying to show that the code is correct.